# Может ли sendto вернуть ноль?

Tags: c++, c, сокет

Может ли `sendto` вернуть ноль при отправке сообщения по UDP сокету, если передаваемое сообщение имеет ненулевую длину?
Документация говорит, что `sendto` возвращает в случае ошибки отрицательное число, а в случае успеха число отправленных байт, которое может быть меньше запрошенного.
Насколько меньше непонятно, возможно ли что вплоть до нуля?
Сокет используется в блокирующем режиме.

Comment: Покажите вызов и распишите, чем равен каждый параметр в момент вызова.

Comment: @ixSci Была такая мысль, но использую библиотеку Poco, у которой под капотом этот sendto.

Comment: Ну Вы же как-то поняли, что она возвращает 0, значит и другие параметры можете вычислить, пусть и не все

Comment: @ixSci Понял (правильно ли), что может возвращать ноль исходя из документации по сокетам, где говориться, что sendto вернет число отправленных байт, которое может быть меньше запрошенного. Как бы ноль это то же меньше запрошенного, поэтому и теряюсь в догадках, возможна ли такая ситуация.

Comment: Ситуация такая возможна. Вас только это интересует?

Comment: @ixSci ещё интересует при каких обстоятельствах она возможна, чтобы адекватно её обработать.

Comment: Погодите, у Вас получилась нулевой результат или же Вы теоретизируете?

Comment: Выходит, что теоретизирую  )

Comment: А что про recv/recvfrom заодно не спросили? (Да, тоже может (в ответ на sendto длиной 0))

Comment: @avp Вопрос в том (первое предложение), что sendto с ненулевой длиной.

Comment: Аааа...., недочитал. Думаю, что нет (если только ошибки в реализации). Доказать не могу, но я бы так никогда не спроектировал.

Answer (score 3):

`sendto` может вернуть 0, но, насколько я понимаю, это возможно лишь в том случае, если в качестве размера буфера этой функции передан 0. В противном случае она либо что-то пошлёт(т.е. вернёт положительный результат), либо же ничего не пошлёт и вернёт `SOCKET_ERROR`.

Comment: Окей, поставлю тогда на всякий случай проверку на ноль с исключением, для будущих поколений.

Comment: И ведь на самом деле посылает 0 байт. А recvfrom реально принимет сообщение 0-й длины и возвращает 0.

Comment: @avp ну это нормально, все равно потом этот ноль байт обрастает заголовками UDP и IP, и в сеть уже вполне обычный ip пакет уходит.